# replicating the list with same fields but different list name using csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I have a list called people , which contains several fields and default fields , i need to create a new list called persons with all the fields in the people list .

```
// load the properties of web project
Web oWeb = oClientContext.Web;
// Get the people list in the web
List sourceList = oClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("people");
ListCreationInformation creationInfo = new ListCreationInformation();
creationInfo.Title = "persons";
creationInfo.Description = "new list created using VS 2013 &CSOM";
creationInfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;
List newList = oClientContext.Web.Lists.Add(creationInfo);

oClientContext.Load(newList);
oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code. Also, I referred this [link](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/) which I found useful.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Security;

namespace ReplicateFields
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("URL"))
            {
                SecureString oSec = new SecureString();
                foreach (char item in "pwd")
                {
                    oSec.AppendChar(item);
                }
                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", oSec);
                List oSouceList = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Person");
                ctx.Load(oSouceList.Fields);
                ctx.Load(oSouceList);

                ListCreationInformation oListinfo = new ListCreationInformation();
                oListinfo.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.GenericList;
                oListinfo.Title = "Persons";
                List oDes = ctx.Web.Lists.Add(oListinfo);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Field oSourceField in oSouceList.Fields)
                {
                    if (oSourceField.Hidden== false)
                    {
                        string schemaTextField = string.Format("<Field Type='{0}' Name='{1}' StaticName='{2}' DisplayName='{3}' />", oSourceField.TypeAsString, oSourceField.InternalName, oSourceField.StaticName, oSourceField.TypeDisplayName);
                        Field simpleTextField = oDes.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaTextField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```